# managing difficulties but not simplicities?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a person or for the phenomena when a person can manage and complete a difficult task but he cannot perform simple tasks?

For example, it is easier for me to create a color image than it is to create a black/white image even though a color image is technically more advanced.

Or for example, if I can complete a Ph D in mathematics, which is difficult, but I can't know or perform something simple e.g. go shopping or answer the phone.

Comment: *Idiot savant* would cover the extreme case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if my answer that there is no definitive answer should be an answer or a comment, but there goes:

I don't think there is one word to describe the behaviours in your example because of the different root causes of those behaviours. In the first example, the person might be a high-functioning autist while in the last example the person might simply suffer from an irrational fear, with the 2nd example simply having to do with talent and/or genetic markup.

Personally, I would pick 'challenged' to describe an individual in a situation where he should function, but doesn't.

Comment: I'd agree with this, there is a huge range of cases where the conditions in the question might be true but for many different reasons.